# Get line break for bib entry in beamer with Biblatex

Tags: beamer, biblatex, apa-style

I use Biblatex in Beamer for citation.

In the preamble, I declared:

```
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
```

and the result I got when I print the bibliography is
[image]

However, I expect the result to be:

> Samy, M. M., Mosaad, M. I., El-Naggar, M. F., & Barakat, S.(2020).
> Reliability support of undependable grid using green energysystems: Economic study.
> IEEE Access, 9, 14528–14539.

May I ask how to get the desired result above with Biblatex? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read Bibtex [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and found a workaround in section 3.1.2 **Preamble Options**, 3.1.2.1 **General**)

```
block=none, space, par, nbpar, ragged
```

This parameter controls the behavior of blocks in the bib entry. For those who are struggling to get the above citation style like me, you should try to set `block=ragged` or `block=par` depends on your need. Detailed information is on page 51.

In my case, those parameters

```
\usepackage[block=ragged, style=apa]{biblatex}
```

completely solve the problem.

### Edit:

For the apa style, if I just use the above parameters, the "year" and "journal" fields also got line break, which is not so good.

Another approach is used `style` and `citestyle` separately in combination with `block`:

```
\usepackage[block=par,style=authoryear,citestyle=apa]{biblatex}
```